# Renamed asp 5 (rc1) project --> Unvalid URI: the hostname could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I unloaded an asp 5 (rc1) project, renamed the folder and reloaded the project. When I tried to debug the project I suddenly got that error (see title). It's absolutely strange and I don't have the slightest clue what I could do about it and which URI seems to be invalid.

I can rename the project back and it works again, but I want to rename it...

Comment: Just for fun I've created a new project that has the same name as I wanted the old one to name to. I got the same error! There must be something oddly cached I think...

Answer (score 1):

After a while I solved the problem:

In the solution folder there is a subdirectory called .vs which contains the config/aplicationhost.config file.
I had a misconfigured site-value (at least for the new asp version). When I altered that value my problem was gone!

Answer (score 0):

As a result of being stuck on a very old version of Visual Studio, whenever I need to rename a project I do the following:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Change folder and file names if required
3. Edit the `.sln` file in notepad and change all the instances of the thing you want to change **including file paths if relevant e.g. in references**
4. Edit the `.csproj` file in notepad and change as above
5. Remove the `.suo` or `.csproj.user` files (note you may have to show hidden files to see them) if they are present - they get regenerated automatically anyway and it's simpler than editing them.

Clunky but reliable.

Also, I've had those kind of caching type problems before, check the output path in your project Build settings and also the virtual path in the Web settings.